# How do I parse-out or access the value returned from jQuery's web-service call?

Tags: jquery, web-services, parsing

I am experimenting with calling a web-service using jQuery.  For some reason the result is returned as XML...and apart from writing a parser myself...there HAS to be a better way of getting at the result.

**This Is The Value Returned:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"Hello World"</string>
```

**This Is The HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/ProjectDialog.asmx/HelloWorld")%>';

    function callWebService() {

        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            complete: onComplete,
            data: null,
            dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            error: onError,
            success: onSuccess,
            url: url
        });
    }

    function onComplete(status, xmlHttpRequest) {
        var stop = "";
    }
    function onError(xmlHttpRequest, status, error) {
        var stop = "";
    }
    function onSuccess(data, status, xmlHttpRequest) {
        var stop = "";
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    });

</script>

<input type="button" value="Run Web Service" onclick="callWebService();" />
```

**This Is The Web Service:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace My.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ProjectDialog
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ProjectDialog : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see my update.  If you specify the `contentType` you will get a valid `json` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three options that would be helpful in this situation -

1. Include this attribute on the Web Service's Method (to return as JSON instead of XML) -

   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
2. Or [Parse the XML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) on client-side
3. Or use an [IHttpHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) rather than a Web Service.  They are easy and more plain to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the [`ScriptMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.responseformat.aspx) to your web service and specify the [ResponseFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.responseformat.aspx) (json is the default)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

This will most likely be your best result since it appears you want to request the data as json anyways based upon your `.ajax()` call.  *Note* the dataType should simply be `json` based upon the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types).

> Different data handling can be
>   achieved by using the dataType option.
>   Besides plain xml, the dataType can be
>   html, json, jsonp, script, or text.

**Update**
It seems if you specify the `contentType` correctly you will get a valid `json` response.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    complete: onComplete,
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    error: onError,
    success: onSuccess,
    url: url
});
```